# Is option to assign ID to every checkbox inside dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

This is my dynamic table

After clicking button it generate table based on input.

```
 $(function () {
    $("#btnGenerate").click(function () {

        var textarea = document.getElementById("inglist");
        var lines = textarea.value.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n").split(/:|,|\n/);
        var lines2 = textarea.value.split(/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/);
        lines.forEach((o, i) => o.id = i + 1);
        var array1=new Array();
        for (var i = 1; i < lines .length; i++) {
                array1.push(lines [i].replace(/\[.*?\]/g, ''));}
        const results = [];
        array1.forEach(line => {
        const filtered = line.split(/([\s\w]+)\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(%?)\s*(\[\d\])?/g).filter(Boolean);
        results.push(filtered);
        });
        var build = new Array();
        build.push(["ING name:", "Total:","unit", "Count it?:","x2?"]);
        var table1 = $("<table />");
        for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
            build.push(results[i]);
        }
        
        var countColumns = build[0].length;
        console.log(countColumns);
        var tables = $("<table /><class='form-control input-md'>");

        //Add the header row.
        var rows = $(tables[0].insertRow(-1));
        for (var i = 0; i < countColumns; i++) {
            var headerCell = $("<th /><class='form-control input-md'>");
            headerCell.html(build[0][i]);
            rows.append(headerCell);
        }

        //Add the data rows.
        for (var i = 1; i < build.length; i++) {
            row = $(tables[0].insertRow(-1));
            for (var j = 0; j < countColumns; j++) {
                var cell = $('<td><input type="checkbox"/>');
                cell.html(build[i][j]);
                row.append(cell);
            }
           
            
        }

        var dvTable1 = $("#dvTable1");
        dvTable1.html("");
        dvTable1.append(tables);
  
});
```

How i can assign dynamic ID to every checkbox ?

And then how to filter only rows where is tick checkbox in 3rd column ( count in?: )

[image: Table view]

Comment: `$("<table /><class='form-control input-md'>")` is not a valid syntax, are you intended to create like `$("<table class='form-control input-md' />")`?

Comment: you can try like this to add dynamic Ids `$(\`<td><input id="checkbox_${i}_${j}" type="checkbox"/>\`)`

Comment: For what reason do you need to add dynamic ids to elements? I ask as creating ids at runtime is counter productive, and generally unnecessary. If you can get a reference to an element to give it an id in the first place, then you don't need to give it an id at all.

Comment: Ok so lets agree that I don't need ID anymore, in this case how I can add to array only rows where checkbox is checked? Could You help by include it into my code?